# How to define project OutputPath in a solution file? (Or how to specify custom project properties in a solution file?)

Tags: msbuild, projects-and-solutions

How can I define project OutputPath in a solution file?

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'DebugUse|AnyCPU' ">
  <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath> <!-- this -->
  <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
  <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Alternatively, I think I could use a custom project property.

```
<OutputPath>$(SolutionOutputPath)\Debug\</OutputPath>
```

But I don't know how define custom project properties in a solution file. I was trying something like:

```
Project(...) = ...
    ProjectSection(ProjectProperties) = preProject
        OutputPath = "C:\Test\Bin"
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure this isn't possible.  The solution file just references project files, so all project-specific options such as output paths and so on, must be contained within the referenced project file.

Comment: You can specify WebSite properties inside a solution file:

ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
  Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/web"
  Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "src\web\"
  ...
EndProjectSection

So, it might be possible to specify other project properties.

Comment: After reflectoring how MSBuild parses the solution file. I found that it is not possible.

Comment: Good point on the WebsiteProperties section, but as far as I can see, that's a bit of an anomaly when compared to the rest of the build system.